# Django forms and set initial value to logged in user?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I have a form like so:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

from django_countries.countries import COUNTRIES

from statuses.models import Status

class StatusForm(forms.Form):
    country = forms.ChoiceField(choices=COUNTRIES)
    mood = forms.IntegerField()
    sleep_quality = forms.IntegerField()
```

This form is only displayed to the users who are logged in, how can I set `request.user` so that when the user submits this form, I can associate the form entry to them? My model looks like the following with the the user FK:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

from django_countries import CountryField

class Status(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    country = CountryField()
    mood = models.SmallIntegerField(default=4)
    sleep_quality = models.SmallIntegerField(default=4)
```

Here is my view for this form as well:

```
@login_required
def index(request, template_name="status/index.html"):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        postdata = request.POST
        form = StatusForm(postdata)
        if form.is_valid():
            messages.success(request, 'Something happened, good!')
            return redirect(urlresolvers.reverse('profile'))
    else:
        form = StatusForm()
    context = RequestContext(request, { 'form': form })
    return render_to_response(template_name, context)
```

I thought maybe I should create a hiddenfield and store request.user in there but that does not seem safe as it can easily be edited with firebug and such. Any suggestions as to how I can store request.user for this form?

Thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to do in your view? The current user is always accessible in `request.user` so you don't need to have a field in the form at all.

Comment: pastylegs, I added my view in the above

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The current user will be present in the request as `request.user` so you don't need to include it in the form. Instead why not leverage [ModelForms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/) as they will deal with linking your object to your form.

```
class StatusForm(forms.ModelForm):
    country = forms.ChoiceField(choices=COUNTRIES)
    # The other fields are automatically included, we just overwrite country

    class Meta:
        model = Status
        exclude = ("user")
```

Then in your view:

```
...
form = StatusForm(request.POST):
    if form.is_valid():
        # Because your model requires that user is present, we validate the form and 
        # save it without commiting, manually assigning the user to the object and resaving
        obj = form.save(commit=False)
        obj.user = request.user
        obj.save()
        messages.success(request, 'Something happened, good!')
        return redirect(urlresolvers.reverse('profile'))
     ...
```